# generating permutations with scalacheck

Tags: scala, scalacheck

I have some generators like this:

```
val fooRepr = oneOf(a, b, c, d, e)
val foo = for (s <- choose(1, 5); c <- listOfN(s, fooRepr)) yield c.mkString("$")
```

This leads to duplicates ... I might get two a's, etc. What I really want is to generate random permutation with exactly 0 or 1 or each of a, b, c, d, or e (with at least one of something), in any order.

I was thinking there must be an easy way, but I'm struggling to even find a hard way. :)

Edited: Ok, this seems to work:

```
val foo = for (s <- choose(1, 5);
               c <- permute(s, a, b, c, d, e)) yield c.mkString("$")

def permute[T](n: Int, gs: Gen[T]*): Gen[Seq[T]] = {
  val perm = Random.shuffle(gs.toList)
  for {
    is <- pick(n, 1 until gs.size)
    xs <- sequence[List,T](is.toList.map(perm(_)))
  } yield xs
}
```

...borrowing heavily from `Gen.pick`.

Thanks for your help, -Eric

Comment: Please post your answer as an answer, not as an edit.

Comment: It wouldn't let me answer my own question, it seems.

Comment: Ah, the big Answer Your Question button. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rex, thanks for clarifying exactly what I'm trying to do, and that's useful code, but perhaps not so nice with scalacheck, particularly if the generators in question are quite complex. In my particular case the generators a, b, c, etc. are generating huge strings.

Anyhow, there was a bug in my solution above; what worked for me is below. I put a tiny project demonstrating how to do this at [github](https://github.com/ebowman/powerset)

The guts of it is below. If there's a better way, I'd love to know it...

```
package powerset

import org.scalacheck._
import org.scalacheck.Gen._
import org.scalacheck.Gen
import scala.util.Random

object PowersetPermutations extends Properties("PowersetPermutations") {

  def a: Gen[String] = value("a")

  def b: Gen[String] = value("b")

  def c: Gen[String] = value("c")

  def d: Gen[String] = value("d")

  def e: Gen[String] = value("e")

  val foo = for (s <- choose(1, 5);
                 c <- permute(s, a, b, c, d, e)) yield c.mkString

  def permute[T](n: Int, gs: Gen[T]*): Gen[Seq[T]] = {
    val perm = Random.shuffle(gs.toList)
    for {
      is <- pick(n, 0 until gs.size)
      xs <- sequence[List, T](is.toList.map(perm(_)))
    } yield xs
  }

  implicit def arbString: Arbitrary[String] = Arbitrary(foo)

  property("powerset") = Prop.forAll {
    a: String => println(a); true
  }
}
```

Thanks,
Eric

Comment: scala.util.Random.shuffle is very handy

Comment: Random.shuffle is great, but not for this use case, which was "to generate random permutation with exactly 0 or 1 or each of a, b, c, d, or e"

Answer (score 3):

<strike>You're not describing a permutation, but the power set (minus the empty set)</strike>Edit: you're describing a combination of a power set and a permutation.  The power set of an indexed set N is isomorphic to 2^N, so we simply (in Scala alone; maybe you want to alter this for use with ScalaCheck):

```
def powerSet[X](xs: List[X]) = {
  val xis = xs.zipWithIndex
  (for (j <- 1 until (1<<xs.length)) yield {
    for ((x,i) <- xis if ((j & (1<<i)) != 0)) yield x
  }).toList
}
```

to generate all possible subsets given a set.  Of course, explicit generation of power sets is unwise if they original set contains more than a handful of elements.  If you don't want to generate all of them, just pass in a random number from `1` until `(1<<(xs.length-1))` and run the inner loop.  (Switch to `Long` if there are 33-64 elements, and to `BitSet` if there are more yet.)  You can then permute the result to switch the order around if you wish.

---

Edit: there's another way to do this if you can generate permutations easily and you can add a dummy argument: make your list one longer, with a `Stop` token.  Then permute and `.takeWhile(_ != Stop)`.  Ta-da!  Permutations of arbitrary length.  (Filter out the zero-length answer if need be.)

Comment: The powerSet function defined above does not correctly generate power sets in Scala 2.11, e.g., powerSet(List(1, 2, 3)).length = 3 != 2^3.   There is now a built-in subsets function: Set(1, 2, 3).subsets.length = 8 = 2^3.  By the way, the use of the word "isomorphic" is also incorrect.

Comment: Thanks!  I guess I forgot to test the code.  It was just an off-by-one error (and the code removes the empty set on purpose).  Anyway, this is a correct use of "isomorphic", but a boring one: there is a bijective mapping between the two sets (no more, no less).  Isomorphism is more interesting when it is between structures more elaborate than bare sets.